# How to get text preview from ckeditor

Tags: cakephp, ckeditor

I am using ckEditor in my app, I am working on Cakephp 2.3.8 . I my CTP file I used this JQ for text preview for ckeditor but its now working, can any one help me to fix this??
  This is my CTP file code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ClaimDescription').keyup(function(){
            $('#target').html($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>

<?= 
    $this->Form->textarea('description', array(
                          'class'=>'ckeditor',  
                          'value'=>$responseInfo['Response']['description'] 
                         )); 
?>
<div id="target"> </div>
```

I want my preview in above div

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the Version or higher version ckeditor had removed the preview tool.

Answer (score -1):

I think this line is wrong.

```
   $('#ckeditor').keyup(function(){
```

Because you are giving ckeditor as an id,but its a class.

Comment: ClaimDescription <-- This is CkEditor's Id , I found it after I posted my question but this also doesn't work